# Angular 2 Inject complex service to service

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I have three services and one component:

- `root.service`
- `abstarct-child.service`
- `extend-child.service`
- `app.component`

The `root.service` injects by using dependency injection the `abstarct-child.service`, like so:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {AbstractChildService} from './abstarct-child.service';

@Injectable()

export class RootService {
    constructor(private _abstractChildService: AbstractChildService) {}
    UseChildServiceDoSomethingFunction(){}  
}
```

The `abstarct-child.service` looks like so:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export abstract class AbstractChildService {
    abstract doSomething(): any ;
}
```

The `extend-child.service` looks like so:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {AbstractChildService} from './abstarct-child.service';

@Injectable()
export class ExtendChildService extends AbstractChildService{

    constructor(private _num: number) { super(); }
    doSomething() : any { return true; }
}
```

The `app.component` provides the `root.service` and the `extend-child.service` **as** the `abstract-child.service` like so:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {RootService} from './root.service';
import {AbstractChildService} from './abstarct-child.service';
import {ExtendChildService} from './extend-child.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    providers: [provide(AbstractChildService, { useClass: ExtendChildService, useValue: this.num})]
})
export class AppComponent {
    @Input('given_Num') num: number;
}
```

I would like to know how can I inject to the `extend-child.service` an object, in this case the `this.num` of `app.component`?

Can anyone find what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't yet fully figured out what you try to accomplish but

```
   provide(AbstractChildService, { 
       useClass: ExtendChildService, 
       useValue: this.num})
```

is not a valid provider.

You can't have an `useClass` **and** `useValue` parameter in one provider, only one at a time.

You also can't use `this.` in a provider in a `@Component()` decorator. When the decorator is evaluated, there is not instance of the component yet where `this.` could refer to.

If you want to provide a number you can use a string or an [OpaqueToken](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OpaqueToken-class.html)

```
provide('MyNumber', {useValue: 10}),
```

and get it injected by

```
constructor(@Inject('MyNumber') private _num: number) { super(); }
```

another way is to use a factory

```
provide(ExtendedChildService, {useFactory: () => { new ExtendedChildService(10)});
```

but `this.` still can't be referred.

Comment: As you can see extend-child.service get an number object by dependency injection, I wont to inject a number to extend-child.service and then inject extend-child.service to root.service. maybe I'm this is a bad way, so if someone knows what its the right way?

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, you can't inject a number by it's type only. For primitive types you need a key that differs from the type and add `@Inject('someKey')` to the constructor parameter. Otherwise DI would't be able to distinguish between serveral provided `string` (number, boolean, ...) values.

Comment: well I got your answer, the problem is that my app.component need to inject the num param, when the num param is injected to app.component to.

Comment: Where does the number come from? I would need more information about the actual problem you're trying to solve to be able to suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: the num is inject from a before-root.component that get the number by using an function on the URL. so if the URL is "www.ex.com/num=1" the before-root.component will have a number parameter called numFromUrl, and inject this parameter in the html like so <app ['given_num']="numFromUrl"></app>

Comment: Hmm, that's way too abstract for me to make any sense. Can you create a Plunker that demonstrates what you want to accomplish?